Azure Graph Explorer query to identify VMs with SQL Server installed
I am tinkering with Graph Explorer in Azure but can't get a solution for what I'm looking for, which is to return a list of VMs on which SQL Server has been installed.  Ultimately, I would like to get the SQL Server version and CU info but one step at a time.
The following query returns results but definitely an incomplete list.  Any suggestions?
resources
| where type == "microsoft.sqlvirtualmachine/sqlvirtualmachines"
| project id, name, resourceGroup, location, version = properties.sqlServerLicenseType, subscriptionId = tolower(subscriptionId)
| join kind=inner (
    resourcecontainers
    | where type == "microsoft.resources/subscriptions"
    | extend subscriptionId = tolower(extract("subscriptions/([^/]+)", 1, id))
    | project subscriptionId, subscriptionName = name
) on subscriptionId
| project subscriptionName, name, resourceGroup, location, version

Tried various Graph Explorer queries

If you want to get the SQL server version, sqlServerLicenseType will not give the expected value.

You can use sqlImageOffer property to get the version and sqlImageSku property to get the edition.

Image Refernce: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.sqlvirtualmachine/sqlvirtualmachines?pivots=deployment-language-bicep#property-values
The correct code will look like,
resources
| where type == "microsoft.sqlvirtualmachine/sqlvirtualmachines"
| project id, name, resourceGroup, location, version = properties['sqlImageOffer'], editon=properties['sqlImageSku'], subscriptionId = tolower(subscriptionId)

Join the result with resourcecontainers to get the subscription_name also.
